# Can a browser apply coumns to text without columned html?

Tags: text-formatting

I would like my browser to take text served as one column and make multiple columns for easier reading.  Ideally I'd like to continue using Firefox in either Windows 7 or OpenSUSE 13.1, but am open to trying a different browser if needed.  Any ideas?

Specifically, I am trying to read the html versions of SICP and HTDP and am now finally willing to agree with the LaTeX postulate that a text line of too many characters is hard to read.

Comment: You could try some reading extensions, like Instapaper or Clearly.

Comment: Did some quick research on those on mobile, will try from desktop soon - down with bronchitis right now though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about browser functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Many moons ago I wrote a smallish javascript bookmarklet which formatted selected blocks of text from web pages like you want and overlaid them on the page. I stopped using it because I found a solution which suited me better. I'll look it out and post it.

I'm not being funny, this is the truth.... I now have a widescreen monitor turned on its side, desktop rotated, so that everything is more readable. Viva longscreen

Comment: Sorry Mark, it's in an old XP archive somewhere - I'm into Linux now. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Interesting idea to use widescreen monitor vertically.  I have one wide and one very old 4:3 - it would be a pain to flip widescreen all the time but I'll see if I like the 4:3 as a permanant vertical.  Not enough rep this one to upvote your answer.